# human language test algorithm

Tags: c#, algorithm, encryption

Let's assume that we have an encrypted byte stream with a suspected decrypting key. I want to decrypt the message with the key and validate the result.

**How to validate result?**

The only known thing about the plain text is it should contain a human language paragraph (one or more). We cannot assume anything more from this text.

I want to develop/use an algorithm that will test the output of the decryption and give me prediction whether the decryption was successful or not.

The algorithm must work with all human languages (won't be specific for one language).

Is this possible? What do you think?

Comment: Just make sure that the majority of the words you decrypted are values in wikipedia, and if so - this is the correct key with high probability. (assuming using a wrong key gives a complete gibberish)

Comment: Do you mean using a dictionary with "known words"? this solution is language specific and I'm want to avoid this.

Comment: Use wikipedia as your on-line dictionary, it will make the solution apply for any language wikipedia exist in, which is almost all of them.

Comment: Can you assume the charset? You say you "decrypt the message" which is a "byte stream". You obviously get bytes in return. How do you know the charset? Therefore, how do you know the used alphabet? Changing the charset can dramatically change the result.

Answer (score 2):

#### Step 0

Decrypt the cipher-text (encrypted) byte array to obtain a plain-text (decrypted) byte array.

If authenticated encryption is used then decrypting with wrong key will fail outright.

If proper padding (PKCS#7/PKCS#5) is used then decrypting with wrong key will fail with the very high probability because the padding will not be decrypted properly.

#### Step 1

Decode the byte array into a char array using proper character encoding **and** `DecoderExceptionFallback` (`CodingErrorAction.REPORT` in Java).

If decrypted byte array contains a sequence of bytes that does not represent a valid character then decoding will fail. Assuming that initial data is proper text in the same encoding the decrypted byte array will contain invalid byte sequences only if the wrong key is used.

#### Step 2

Actually, the first two steps will expose the wrong key with the very high probability.

Now, in the unlikely situation when a wrong key is used and decryption miraculously resulted in the properly padded data and the decoded data contained only valid byte sequences for the selected character encoding, you have a textual data and can use two simple (but still empirical) ideas that do not require dictionaries or online access:

1. In most sane natural languages the words are separated by white-space.
2. In most sane natural languages the words are made of letters.

The Unicode General Category property is very helpful in determining the type of character without being specific for a single language, and most regex implementations allow to specify the regex pattern in terms of Unicode categories.

First, split the text by `Separator` and `Punctuation` Unicode categories. The result is a list of "words" devoid of white-space and punctuation.

Second, match each word with a `Letter+` pattern. The rate of words that match to the words that do not match it is high for any natural text. It can be high for a specifically constructed text-like gibberish too but it certainly will be low for a random sequence of characters.

Answer (score 1):

You can analyse the text and then calculate the letter frequencies. If the letter frequency is way of chart you could say that the encryption has gone wrong. And if you mix this with the occurrences of spaces you have a reasonable solid way of saying if the encryption was successful.

[Wikipedia on Letter frequency](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Letter_frequency)

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to tell whether a bytestream contains a message in a human language without any more assumptions. First and foremost, you absolutely need to know the encoding (or a few possible encodings).

Then I am 99.9% sure that there is no generic way to infer whether a large group of (e.g.) ASCII-chars has a meaning in any human language without the use of some kind of dictionary. If you could narrow it down to a language family, *maybe* you would be able to detect grammatic constructs - but I am really just speculating. Even if it is possible it will not be a trivial task to design the heuristics.

That said, I can only second the suggestions in the comments: Use wikipedia! Create your own dictionary from it or use it online - either way, I believe it's your best bet.